# Installation Pauses (Corrected by User Input)

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 Server on some virtual machines via virt-manager. However, when installing, the installation frequently pauses while preparing/configuring various packages or other steps. Interestingly, basic user input (arrow keys) seems to force the installation to continue normally for 15-30 seconds.

I'm a little worried that my user input is being misinterpreted as requests to cancel/continue. Any ideas as to what's going on here? Should I just redownload the image or something?

Comment: Just let it work.

Comment: Eventually I'd like this to be automated, though. Also means I have to babysit the installation and press arrow keys every minute or it'll just stop.

Comment: You don't need to babysit. Just leave it alone.